# Change facebook plugin with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, html, plugins

Is it possible to remove the like button on top of the 'Like box' facebook plugin with Jquery ?

I import the like box from Facebook and i would like to remove this like button, but facebook doesnt want me to remove it.. So i though i could remove it with JQuery.

I found that the block which would support this button and its text is inside a  with class 'pam' and 'clearfix'

so i tried hiding this with these lines of code, but it doesnt want to change

```
$('.pam').css("display", "none");
$('.pam').hide();
```

Anyone has any idea on how to hide this ?

(Imporing with HTML5 method, but anything would do if i need to change)

-- Also if you know how to change the text color (post title color), i would greatly appreaciate all this information !

Thanks for all of those that will try to help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to alter Facebook's social widgets directly. You cannot access iframes cross-domain with javascript, due to browsers' same origin policy.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

The only hack-ish approach you could take would be to offset the iframe from your DOM to hide the top portion of the widget, or overlay something on top via css on a higher z-index layer. Although that would not be very compliance friendly with Facebook's policy, just for the warning.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, i will keep all this in mind, i did thought that i could not change it, but i still asked just in case something could be done :)